# Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0 How to loop through all line items and total the quantity

Tags: netsuite, sublist, suitescript2.0

I am trying to loop through all the line items of the Inventory Adjustment screen in Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0 and total the quantity (Adjust By Qty) field in order to check that it sums to zero (the first line must hold the negative value that the other positive lines must match). Unfortunately I am new to this and I also can't find any examples of how to do this. I also need to eventually update the lot number to increment for each line from the first line's number. All lines must also have the same parent item.

I've had lots of issues in doing this namely that the quantity field change event fires multiple times, alerts would be annoying to users on the way to a total of zero, the screen can only be saved at the end when the total is 0, etc. My current issue is that my code just sums the line being entered (the current line) even though I loop through the lines. I tried to use `getSublistValue` instead of `getCurrentSublistValue` but this gave me an error message. I tried to use `selectLine` but this tries to move the currently active line while the line is still being entered and required fields remain. I can't find any example code for `getSublistFields` to potentially get all the values.

We are using Netsuite 2018.2 and I'm missing SQL.

How can this be done in Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0 and can I also update sublist subrecords (lot number in Inventory Detail icon) at the same time?

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define([], function () {

   // Client Script global variables.
   var allowSave = true;
   var firstItemNegative = false;
   var firstItemParentID = -9999;

   function fieldChanged(context) {

      var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;    // Current opened record.
      var sublistName = context.sublistId;          // The internal ID of the sublist.
      var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;       // The internal ID of the field that was changed.
      var currentLine = context.line;               // Line number (first line has value = 0) of Item User is on.

      // Run when the Item field of the inventory sublist changed.
      // Item for some reason does not fire a change event, so using item description instead.
      // This means the description has to be required for these types of items.
      if (sublistName === 'inventory' && sublistFieldName === 'description') {

         // Check how many lines exist in the inventory sublist.
         var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'inventory'});
         // console.info("SS lines: " + lines);

      // Run when the Adjust Qty. By field of the inventory sublist changed.
      } else if (sublistName === 'inventory' && sublistFieldName === 'adjustqtyby') {

         console.info("SS fieldChanged: " + (context.sublistId || "record") + "." + context.fieldId);

         // Check how many lines exist in the inventory sublist.
         var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'inventory'});
         console.info("SS lines: " + lines);

         var total;      // Total used to check whether sum of quantities is zero.
         var quantity;   // Used to hold quantity for current line item.

         for (var i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++) {
console.info("SS total start: " + total);
            currentRecord.selectLine({
               sublistId: "inventory",
               line: i
            });
            // If we are on the first item line.
            if (i === 0) {
               // Get the first item line's Adjust Qty. By field value.
               total = parseFloat(currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                  sublistId: "inventory",
                  fieldId: "adjustqtyby",
                  line: i
               }));
console.info("SS total first line: " + total);
               // If the quantity of the first line is positive then this is a real Inventory Adjustment
               // and not a roll that was cut into smaller inventory.
               if (total >= 0) {
                  firstItemNegative = false;
               } else {
                  firstItemNegative = true;
               }
            } else if (i > 0) {   // For non-first lines.
               // Get the current item line's Adjust Qty. By field value.
               // Note that the value could be invalid in which case 0 is used.
               quantity = (parseFloat(currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                  sublistId: "inventory",
                  fieldId: "adjustqtyby",
                  line: i
               })) || 0);
console.info("SS quantity: " + quantity);
               // If the first item is negative then we have to keep a running total of the quantities.
               if (firstItemNegative) {
                  total = total + quantity;
console.info("SS total other lines: " + total);
               } else {   // If the first item is positive we have to check that there are no other negative quantities.
                  if (quantity < 0) {
                     allowSave = false;
                     // Show modeless Netsuite banner message at top of screen that is replaced by subsequent messages.
                     // If you use the same id in the first parameter it will overwrite the message, if you supply a different id you will see new messages uniquely in the page.
                     showAlertBox(
                        "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
                        "Error:",          // Message header.
                        'Inventory Item line number ' + (i + 1) + ' has a negative "Adjust Qty. By" field value. Negative values are only allowed for the first item.',
                        3,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
                        "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
                     );
                     break;
                  }
               }
            }   // if (i === 0)

         }   // for (var i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++)
console.info("SS total end: " + total);
         // If the total of the quantities are not zero then error. Allow if only the first line exists.
         if (total !== 0 && lines !== 0) {
            allowSave = false;
            if (total < 0) {
               showAlertBox(
                  "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
                  "Error:",          // Message header.
                  'Error: The total of the "Adjust Qty. By" fields must equal zero. You are under by ' + (-total),
                  3,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
                  "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
               );
            } else {
               showAlertBox(
                  "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
                  "Error:",          // Message header.
                  'Error: The total of the "Adjust Qty. By" fields must equal zero. You are over by ' + total,
                  3,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
                  "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
               );
            }
         } else {
            allowSave = true;
         }

      }   //  if (sublistName === 'inventory' && sublistFieldName === 'description')

      // Clear any error messages to show that all fields validated.
      if (allowSave) {
         showAlertBox(
            "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
            "Success:",          // Message header.
            'Validation passed.',
            0,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
            "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
         );
      }

   }   // fieldChanged

   function saveRecord() {
      // debugger;
      console.info("SS saveRecord");
      if (!allowSave) {
         alert("Error: Save failed. There are error messages at the top of the page.");
      }
      return allowSave;
   }   // saveRecord

   return {
      fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
      saveRecord: saveRecord
   };

});   // Define
```

Comment: What error did you receive on using `getSublistValue`?

Comment: I think it was something to the effect that `currentRecord` does not have `getSublistValue`.

Comment: AFAIK `getSublistValue` method is available in both dynamic and non-dynamic mode.  Other thing is you cannot use `currentRecord.selectLine` in client script as it will change user selected line

Comment: I'll try and reproduce it to get the correct error message. How does one iterate through the items if you can't use selectLine?

Comment: you need to use `getSublistValue` as it does not affects current selected line, but you cannot use `setSublistValue` in non-dynamic mode.

Comment: I have checked and the `currentRecord` is using dynamic mode. The error I get with `currentRecord.getSublistValue` is `SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION CurrentRecord.getSublistValue`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273166148.html) for using `getSublistValue`.

Comment: I have looked at the help. I'm trying to change my use of currentRecord.getSublistValue to use a N/record version of currentRecord but then I have new issues - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944350/netsuite-suitescript-2-0-how-to-complete-the-parameters-of-the-n-record-load-fun.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but it looks like you have an 'off by one' error in your for loop condition.  Attempting to `getSublistValue()` on a line that doesn't exist would cause an error.

Comment: Thanks Krypton. It looks like I'll have to loop for lines that have been added and then use getCurrentSublistValue for the line that is partially added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Krypton for solving this one, been struggling for days. The following code now works:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/search'], function (s) {

   // Client Script global variables.
   var allowSave = true;
   var firstItemNegative = false;
   var firstItemParentID = -9999;

   function fieldChanged(context) {

      var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;    // Current opened record.
      var sublistName = context.sublistId;          // The internal ID of the sublist.
      var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;       // The internal ID of the field that was changed.
      var currentLine = context.line;               // Line number (first line has value = 0) of Item User is on.

      // Run when the Item field of the inventory sublist changed.
      // Item for some reason does not fire a change event, so using item description instead.
      // This means the description has to be required for these types of items.
      if (sublistName === 'inventory' && sublistFieldName === 'description') {

         // Check how many lines exist in the inventory sublist.
         var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'inventory'});
         // console.info("SS lines: " + lines);

         // if (currentRecord.isDynamic) {
         //    console.info("SS isDynamic: true");   // currentRecord is Dynamic.
         // } else {
         //    console.info("SS isDynamic: false");
         // }

      // Run when the Adjust Qty. By field of the inventory sublist changed.
      } else if (sublistName === 'inventory' && sublistFieldName === 'adjustqtyby') {

         console.info("SS fieldChanged: " + (context.sublistId || "record") + "." + context.fieldId);
         console.info("SS currentLine: " + currentLine);

         // Check how many lines exist in the inventory sublist.
         var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'inventory'});
         console.info("SS lines: " + lines);

         var total;      // Total used to check whether sum of quantities is zero.
         var quantity;   // Used to hold quantity for current line item.

         for (var i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {

            // If we are on the first item line.
            if (i === 0) {

               if (i === currentLine) {
                  // Get the first item line's Adjust Qty. By field value.
                  // Note that the value could be invalid in which case 0 is used.
                  // For partially entered lines.
                  total = (parseFloat(currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                     sublistId: "inventory",
                     fieldId: "adjustqtyby"
                  })) || 0);
               } else {
                  // Get the first item line's Adjust Qty. By field value.
                  // For completed lines that have been Added.
                  total = (parseFloat(currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                     sublistId: "inventory",
                     fieldId: "adjustqtyby",
                     line: i
                  })) || 0);
               }
               console.info("SS total first line: " + total);

               // If the quantity of the first line is positive then this is a real Inventory Adjustment
               // and not a roll that was cut into smaller inventory.
               if (total >= 0) {
                  firstItemNegative = false;
               } else {
                  firstItemNegative = true;
               }

            } else if (i > 0) {   // For non-first lines.

               if (i === currentLine) {
                  // Get the current item line's Adjust Qty. By field value.
                  quantity = (parseFloat(currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({
                     sublistId: "inventory",
                     fieldId: "adjustqtyby"
                  })) || 0);
               } else {
                  // Get the current item line's Adjust Qty. By field value.
                  quantity = (parseFloat(currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                     sublistId: "inventory",
                     fieldId: "adjustqtyby",
                     line: i
                  })) || 0);
               }
               console.info("SS quantity: " + quantity);

               // If the first item is negative then we have to keep a running total of the quantities.
               if (firstItemNegative) {
                  total = total + quantity;
                  console.info("SS total other lines: " + total);
               } else {   // If the first item is positive we have to check that there are no other negative quantities.
                  if (quantity < 0) {
                     allowSave = false;
                     // Show modeless Netsuite banner message at top of screen that is replaced by subsequent messages.
                     // If you use the same id in the first parameter it will overwrite the message, if you supply a different id you will see new messages uniquely in the page.
                     showAlertBox(
                        "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
                        "Error:",          // Message header.
                        'Inventory Item line number ' + (i + 1) + ' has a negative "Adjust Qty. By" field value. Negative values are only allowed for the first item.',
                        3,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
                        "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
                     );
                     break;
                  }
               }
            }   // if (i === 0)

         }   // for (var i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++)
         console.info("SS total end: " + total);

         // If the total of the quantities are not zero then error. Allow if only the first line exists.
         if (total !== 0 && lines !== 0) {
            allowSave = false;
            if (total < 0) {
               showAlertBox(
                  "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
                  "Error:",          // Message header.
                  'Error: The total of the "Adjust Qty. By" fields must equal zero. You are under by ' + (-total),
                  3,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
                  "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
               );
            } else {
               showAlertBox(
                  "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
                  "Error:",          // Message header.
                  'Error: The total of the "Adjust Qty. By" fields must equal zero. You are over by ' + total,
                  3,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
                  "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
               );
            }
         } else {
            allowSave = true;
         }

      }   //  if (sublistName === 'inventory' && sublistFieldName === 'description')

      // Clear any error messages to show that all fields validated.
      if (allowSave) {
         showAlertBox(
            "my_element_id",   // Dummy element id of alert.
            "Success:",          // Message header.
            'Validation passed.',
            0,                 // Colour of alert: 0 - Success (green), 1 - Information (blue), 2 - Warning (yellow), 3 - Error (red)
            "","","",""        // Not sure what this does.
         );
      }

   }   // fieldChanged
   function saveRecord() {
      // debugger;
      console.info("SS saveRecord");
      if (!allowSave) {
         alert("Error: Save failed. There are error messages at the top of the page.");
      }
      return allowSave;
   }   // saveRecord

   return {
      fieldChanged: fieldChanged,
      saveRecord: saveRecord
   };

});   // Define
```