# Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0 How to complete the parameters of the N/record load function

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to call the Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0 `N/record` module's load function, but I am unsure as to what to pass for the parameters. Basically I would like a `N/record` with the same id (primary key) of the current record in the UI, that I can use to loop through the sublist items.

I'm not sure how to use the Records Browser in order to find the correct type and id. The Records Browser does not have the type, so I guessed at the name. There are also multiple fields that could be the primary key id. Is it `tranid` or `externalid` or some other field? I'm specifically interested in the Inventory Adjustment form. `externalid` is undefined and `tranid` is To Be Generated.

Is it possible to get a `N/Record` based on the `currentRecord` in this manner or will it also suffer from the same issues I have with `currentRecord` (I can't use `selectLine` to step through the sublist items, sublist items have not been saved yet and the last one is partially completed)?

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/search', 'N/record'], function (s, r) {
   function fieldChanged(context) {
      var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
      var sublistName = context.sublistId;
      var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
      var currentLine = context.line;
      var recordId = currentRecord.getValue({fieldId: "externalid"});
      var record = r.load({
         type: r.Type.INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT,
         id: recordId,
         isDynamic: true
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a N/Record based on the currentRecord

Yes, although `N/record` module is used to load/create records. So in order to use `N/record` module, you need to make sure that your record already exists or you are creating new.

InternalId specified at the top of the Records Browser page is the recordType that you need to pass as `type` to `record module`.

Also try using async version of record load. i.e `record.load.promise` in client script.

[image: Selected text is the recordType]

Comment: I assume you have to change the internal id from inventoryadjustment to INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT? Also what about the id parameter?

Comment: id is internalid of the record that you want to load. Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267258486.html) on how to load records

Comment: id is not the internalid the Netsuite help uses a number in it's example: var objRecord = record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
    id: 157,
    isDynamic: true,
});

Comment: and what is the internalid of your current record(Inventory Adjustment)? In the above example 157 is internalid/id

Comment: I used `var recordId = currentRecord.getValue({fieldId: "tranid"});` to get the id of the record, but it is To Be Generated, presumably because the record has not been saved yet. The internal id is inventoryadjustment and not a number.

Comment: `inventoryadjustment` will be type and as I mentioned above record needs to pre-exists in order to load it. Also tranid is not id use `currentRecord.id` to get internalid

Comment: `currentRecord.id` evaluates to `null` (possibly `undefined`) in a `fieldChanged` event.

Comment: id and tranid are not assigned unless record is saved and in your case record is still not saved so you cannot load the record and currentRecord.id will be null since record is in create  mode and not yet saved.